# AutoFac WebApi dependency resolver

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac

Is it bad to (below) every time the container changes with new apicontrollers:

```
//update webapi
                var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
                config.DependencyResolver = resolver;
```

Is there a  better way to signal to the resolver that a change has been made in the container so that webapi see's the new controller?

I am loading new dlls which have new api controllers.  I update them with a new builder:
`builder.Update(config)` However at the moment this does not signal the resolver nor webapi to see the new controller.  This works fine if the controllers are present at first, or if I run the code above.

At the moment I am doing self hosted webapi.

Comment: Why do you want to load assemblies dynamically? Assemblies can never be unloaded. If you restart the app domain (what will automatically happen when when you change anything in the /bin folder of a IIS web app) the problem will not exist.

Comment: I want to create a module system, where a dll can have its html content and its webapi back-end loaded modularly.

Comment: But is there a requirement for the web service to keep running or is it okay if the app domain is restarted?

Comment: When the app is running in iis mode, the app-domain can restart, however when the app is embedded and running the application cannot restart.